# how to force boundary type to stationary for oculus quest 2 in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, boundary

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything. I want to force boundary type to stationary for oculus quest 2 with unity in my own VR game. Is there a way to this?

I am using OVR. I couldn't find a solution in it. I tried something with XRDevice.SetTrackingSpaceType but no result. It's already deprecated.

Comment: I guess no one will be able to solve this problem